# AWS CLI command completion with fish shell

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, fish, tab-completion

Has anybody been able to set up auto-complete for the AWS CLI with fish shell? The AWS documentation only offers the guide for bash, tcsh, and zsh.

Bash exports the variables `COMP_LINE` and `COMP_POINT` that is used by the aws_completer script provided by the Amazon. Is there any equivalent for fish? I'm new with the fish shell and I'm giving it a try.

Comment: Fish supports completions using its own [`complete`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#complete). Read more about it in [Writing your own completions](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#completion-own). I haven't setup AWS CLI on Fish, but for the [looks of it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-command-completion.html) you will need to write your own completion file. See [here](https://github.com/bpinto/oh-my-fish/blob/master/plugins/git-flow/completions/git.fish) for an example on how to write completions.

Answer (score 17):

Building upon [David Roussel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191084/david-roussel)'s answers I cooked up the following:

```
function __fish_complete_aws
    env COMP_LINE=(commandline -pc) aws_completer | tr -d ' '
end

complete -c aws -f -a "(__fish_complete_aws)"
```

Put this in a file `$HOME/.config/fish/completions/aws.fish` so fish can autoload it when necessary.

`aws_completer` appends a space after every option it prints and that gets escaped as `\` so trimming it solves the trailing backslashes.

Now we can test the completion with the following:

```
> complete -C'aws co'
codebuild
codecommit
codepipeline
codestar
cognito-identity
cognito-idp
cognito-sync
comprehend
comprehendmedical
connect
configure
configservice
```

Using the `commandline -c` helps if you move back the cursor since it cuts the command line at the cursor so `aws_completer` can offer the right completions.

Answer (score 5):

I also want to get his to work, and I've made some progress, but it's not perfect.

First I look some advise from [here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/perlancar/2014/11/comparing-programmable-tab-completion-in-bash-zsh-tcsh-and-fish.html) which helps to seem how to emulate the bash environment variables that as_completer expects.

Putting it together I get this:

```
complete -c aws -f -a '(begin; set -lx COMP_SHELL fish; set -lx COMP_LINE (commandline); /usr/local/bin/aws_completer; end)'
```

That mostly works but I get spurious extra slashes, so if I try to complete "aws ec2 describe-instances --" I get:

```
dave@retino ~> aws ec2 describe-instances --
--ca-bundle\             --color\          --filters\               --no-dry-run\        --output\      --region\
--cli-connect-timeout\   --debug\          --generate-cli-skeleton  --no-paginate\       --page-size\   --starting-token\
--cli-input-json\        --dry-run\        --instance-ids\          --no-sign-request\   --profile\     --version\
--cli-read-timeout\      --endpoint-url\   --max-items\             --no-verify-ssl\     --query\
```

It looks to me like there is a trailing whitespace char, but I tried to remove it using sed:

```
complete -c aws -f -a '(begin; set -lx COMP_SHELL fish; set -lx COMP_LINE (commandline); echo (/usr/local/bin/aws_completer | sed -e \'s/[ ]*//\') ; end)'
```

But this doesn't seem to help.  It seems that fish expects a different output format than bash for it's completer.  And indeed the [fish decimation for the complete builtin](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#complete) doe say that it expects a space separated list.

So I tried joining the lines with xargs:

```
complete -c aws -f -a '(begin; set -lx COMP_SHELL fish; set -lx COMP_LINE (commandline); echo (/usr/local/bin/aws_completer | sed -e \'s/[ ]*//\') | xargs echo ; end)'
```

But this doesn't work either.  I just get one completion

This is annoying, I'm so close, but it doesn't work!

Comment: @ridiculous_fish do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: A new question? To my knowledge pinging someone under your answer like the above makes them blind to the fact

Comment: Using sed to strip off a trailing whitespace character worked for me, but you don't want to use a fish sub-shell when doing it, since that ends up concatenating the output into a single, giant argument.

This worked for me:

`complete --command aws --no-files  --arguments '(begin; set --local --export COMP_SHELL fish; set --local --export COMP_LINE (commandline); /usr/local/bin/aws_completer | sed \'s/ $//\'; end)'`

Answer (score 4):

While the provided answer doesn't answer the question directly about the using `fish`; I intend to provide an answer to help in the context of `auto-completion` & `shell`.

Amazon has launched a new CLI based tool forked from [AWSCLI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/super-charge-your-aws-command-line-experience-with-aws-shell).

> aws-shell is a command-line shell program that provides convenience
> and productivity features to help both new and advanced users of the
> AWS Command Line Interface. Key features include the following.
>
> **Fuzzy auto-completion**
>
> - Commands (e.g. ec2, describe-instances, sms, create-queue)
> - Options (e.g. --instance-ids, --queue-url)
> - Resource identifiers (e.g. Amazon EC2 instance IDs, Amazon SQS queue URLs, Amazon SNS topic names)
>   [image]
>
> **Dynamic in-line documentation**
>
> - Documentation for commands and options are displayed as you type
>   [image]
>
> **Execution of OS shell commands**
>
> - Use common OS commands such as cat, ls, and cp and pipe inputs and outputs without leaving the shell
>   [image]
> - Export executed commands to a text editor To find out more, check out the related blog post on [AWS Command Line Interface blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/super-charge-your-aws-command-line-experience-with-aws-shell/).
>
> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your `.config/fish/config.fish`

```
complete --command aws --no-files --arguments '(begin; set --local --export COMP_SHELL fish; set --local --export COMP_LINE (commandline); aws_completer | sed \'s/ $//\'; end)'
```

In case you want to make sure that aws-cli is installed:

```
test -x (which aws_completer); and complete --command aws --no-files --arguments '(begin; set --local --export COMP_SHELL fish; set --local --export COMP_LINE (commandline); aws_completer | sed \'s/ $//\'; end)'
```

All credits belong to this [issue thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1079) and a comment by an awesome SO contributor @scooter-dangle.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to map bash's completion to fish's.

See [the npm completions](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/527c932e9396ed9c37dccc632543aa88330dbfcd/share/completions/npm.fish#L37-L53).

However it's probably still better to write a real fish script (it's not hard!).

Answer (score -1):

The command I use in my virtualenv/bin/activate is this:

```
complete -C aws_completer aws
```

Looks like aws-cli has fish support too. There is a bundled installer provided with aws-cli that might be worth checking out: [activate.fish](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-command-completion.html). I found it in the same bin directory as the aws command.

For example:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:/data/src$ tail -n1 ~/venv/bin/activate
complete -C aws_completer aws
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:/data/src$ source ~/venv/bin/activate
(venv) ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:/data/src$ aws s3         <- hitting TAB here
cp        ls        mb        mv        presign   rb        rm        sync      website
(venv) ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:/data/src$ aws s3
```

Comment: @cig0 works fine for me. Added example output showing hitting tab at line 4 after `aws s3`. Maybe something with your environment.